# Using threads to alternate between words starting with a vowel or consonant

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to have the `main()` create two threads which will run two functions:

- `vow` - prints words which start with a vowel
- `cons` - prints words which start with a consonant.

These words come from a text file and are read into a vector. The current code  prints out the words in correct order, but is labeling every word as one which starts with a vowel. I am using the test sentence: `"Operating Systems class at college."`

If I have the if statement currently checking for all vowels changed to only check for an O (uppercase o) it labels "Operating" as a vowel, which is correct, and the rest as consonants. What is going wrong?

I am not allowed to use synchronization techniques.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int cons(string temp){
    cout << "cons:  " << temp << endl;
    //this_thread::yield();
    return 0;
}

int vow(string temp){
    cout << "vow:   " << temp << endl;
    //this_thread::yield();
    return 0;
}


int main(){
    string sentence, temp;
    ifstream ifs;
    ofstream ofs;
    vector <thread> wordThreads;

    ifs.open("phrase.txt");
    getline(ifs, sentence);
    istringstream s(sentence);
    istream_iterator<string> begin(s), end;
    vector<string> words(begin, end); 

    ifs.close();

    for(int i=0; i<(int)words.size(); i++) {
        temp = words[i];
        if(temp[0] == 'A'||'a'||'E'||'e'||'I'||'i'||'O'||'o'||'U'||'u') {
            thread threadOne(vow, temp);
            threadOne.join();
        }
        else {
            thread threadTwo(cons, temp);
            threadTwo.join();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: `temp[0] == 'A'||'a'||'E'||'e'||'I'||'i'||'O'||'o'||'U'||'u'` there is the issue. you have to write temp[0] == 'A' || temp[0] == 'a' || temp[0] == 'E' || ...

Comment: Wow, worst use ,of threading _ever!_ :-) Why can't assignments reflect reality a little more? Not OPs fault of course, but whoever set that assignment should be tarred and feathered, then run out of town.

Answer (score 2):

`temp[0] == 'A'||'a'||'E'||'e'||'I'||'i'||'O'||'o'||'U'||'u'` doesn't evaluate to what you think it does; that will always result in the branch being taken. `temp[0] == 'A'` is first evaluated; if false, each subsequent character literal expression is evaluated and treated as a condition for the branch. Since `'A'`, `'a'`, etc. are all non-zero, the branch will always be taken. Perhaps you meant something like this?

```
temp[0] == 'A' || temp[0] == 'a' || temp[0] == 'E' || ...
```

... or perhaps something like this:

```
std::string vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu";
...
if (vowels.find(temp[0]) > 0) {
  ...
}
```